# Permission propagation

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions

We are trying to access with contacts friends_birthday permission.

After saving app configuration, we get this message: "Changes saved. Note that your changes may take several minutes to propagate to all servers."

It was two weeks ago, but we still can't access to contacts birthdays.

How could we do it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are changing this information in the app settings in https://developers.facebook.com/apps 
how do your customer do login in your app? did you update the permission requests there?